# Quarkus extension (io.quarkus:quarkus-spring-data-jpa) repository can't return Collection of Strings

Tags: java, quarkus

I'm migrating my service to Quarkus from SpringBoot stack. 
Why the following code doesn't work in Quarkus? Is that a bug?

```
public interface GenericDictionaryRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Dictionary, UUID> {

    @Query("select distinct(d.type) from Dictionary d order by d.type")
    List<String> findAllTypes();

}
```

Error message

```
io.quarkus.builder.BuildException: Build failure: Build failed due to errors
    [error]: Build step io.quarkus.spring.data.deployment.SpringDataJPAProcessor#build threw an exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.String was not part of the Quarkus index
```

My version properties for Gradle:

```
quarkusPluginVersion=1.3.1.Final
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-universe-bom
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus
quarkusPlatformVersion=1.3.1.Final
```

Comment: did you solve it ? did you open a issue in github for this ?

Comment: I haven't. Now, I'm just using full Entity for that. Since that time 1.4.x released and I haven't checked it.

Comment: In my case the error was ..."java.lang.Iterable was not part of the Quarkus index." To solve simply required renaming all my custom queries named "findAll" to something else, so they wouldn't clash with the JPA built-in Iterable ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was a method naming problem. I had to put a break point in the quarkus code to find what method was wrongly spelled.

In my case the method was `findAllOrderByNameAsc` and when I used `findAllByOrderByNameAsc`, it worked.

To debug the app you have to execute the command `./mvnw quarkus:dev -Ddebug -Dsuspend=true` and connect to remote from your IDE.

Hope it helps.